# JavaFX increasing a circle's radius by clicking on it

Tags: java, javafx, geometry

I'm trying to create a JavaFX program that creates a circle when you click on the screen. There can be many circles at once. But I can't think of a solution to how to increase a circle's radius when I click on it again.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button reset;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchor;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane border;

    Circle circle = new Circle();
    int radius = 20;

    public void initialize (URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        anchor.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            border.getChildren().add(circle = new Circle());
            circle.setCenterX(event.getX());
            circle.setCenterY(event.getY());
            circle.setRadius(radius);     
        });

        reset.setOnAction(event -> {
            border.getChildren().clear();
        });

        circle.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            circle.setRadius(radius * 1.5);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you declare as `circle` is never added to the scene graph. So it never appears and its `mouseClicked` handler is never invoked.

On the other hand, the circles you do add to the scene graph have no mouse clicked handler associated with them. You need to register a handler when you create them:

```
anchor.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    border.getChildren().add(circle);
    circle.setCenterX(event.getX());
    circle.setCenterY(event.getY());
    circle.setRadius(radius);
    circle.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() * 1.5);
        // prevent event from propagating to pane:
        e.consume();
    });
});
```

And now just get rid of the `circle` instance field and the handler you associate with it entirely.